# Improving performance on chunked lists

Tags: performance, haskell

I have a simple problem: Given a list of integers, read the first line as `N`. Then, read the next N lines and return the sum of them. Repeat until `N` = 0.

My first approach was using this:

```
main = interact $ unlines . f . (map read) . lines

f::[Int] -> [String]
f (n:ls)
  | n == 0    = []
  | otherwise = [show rr] ++ (f rest)
     where (xs, rest) = splitAt n ls
           rr = sum xs
f _ = []
```

But it's relatively slow. I've profiled it using

```
ghc -O2 --make test.hs -prof -auto-all -caf-all -fforce-recomp -rtsopts
time ./test +RTS -hc -p -i0.001 < input.in
```

Where `input.in` is a test input where the first line is 100k, followed by 100k random numbers, followed by 0. We can see in the Figure below that it's using O(N) memory:

[image]

**EDITED**: *My original question was comparing 2 similarly slow approaches. I've updated it to compare with an optimized approach below*

Now, if I do the sum iteratively, instead of calling `sum`, I get constant amount of memory

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

main = interact $ unlines . g . (map read) . lines

g::[Int] -> [String]
g (n:ls)
  | n == 0    = []
  | otherwise = g' n ls 0
g _ = []

g' n (l:ls) !cnt
  | n == 0 = [show cnt] ++ (g (l:ls))
  | otherwise = g' (n-1) ls (cnt + l)
```

[image]

I'm trying to understand what is causing the performance loss in the first example. I would guess everything there could be lazily evaluated?

Comment: Untested guess: perhaps your two invocations of `read` in the first example are not using the same type, e.g. there's some `Integer` vs `Int` issue. (edit: this comment was about a previous version of the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know precisely what is causing the difference. But I can show you this:

```
Data.Map> sum [1 .. 1e8]
Out of memory.

Data.Map> foldl' (+) 0 [1 .. 1e8]
5.00000005e15
```

For some reason, `sum = foldl (+) 0`, rather than `foldl'` (with the apostrophe). The difference is that the latter function is more strict, so it uses virtually no memory. The lazy version, by contrast, does this:

```
sum [1..100]
1 + sum [2..100]
1 + 2 + sum [3..100]
1 + 2 + 3 + sum [4.100]
...
```

In other words, it creates a giant expression that says 1 + 2 + 3 + ... And then, right at the end, it tries to evaluate it all. Well, obviously, that's going to eat a lot of RAM. By using `foldl'` instead of `foldl`, you make it do the additions *immediately*, rather than pointlessly storing them in RAM.

You probably also want to do I/O using `ByteString` rather than `String`; but the laziness difference will probably give you a big speed boost on its own.

Comment: Thanks! I think the approach I was trying is indeed being inefficient  by trying to load the entire data in memory. I've updated with an optimized approach to compare the differences.

I'm still unsure on why the first approach can't process streamlined as the second one.

Thanks for the ByteString suggestion. I'll give it a try.

Comment: BTW, the ByteString was actually what I needed. The ideas I've tried only improved memory footprint, not speed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that laziness is what prevents your first and second version from being equivalent.

Consider the result created from the input "numbers"

```
1
garbage_here
2
3
5
0
```

The first version would give a result list [error "...some parse error", 8], which you can safely look at the second element of, while the second version errors near immediately.  It seems hard to achieve the first in a streaming way.

Even without laziness, though, getting from the first to the second version may be more than GHC can handle - it would need to have fusion rewriting rules combining `foldl/foldl'` on the first element of a tuple with `splitAt`.  And GHC has [only recently](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7994) got to the point where it can fuse `foldl/foldl'` at all.

Comment: yeah I think without rewriting it in a smarter way, the compiler can't really figure that out :(